# Why OpenGL grayscale texture performance gain not achieved?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, metal

I use OpenGL compute shader to process image, the shader only copy source texture to target texture.

In first test, source and target textures are both **BGR8**, in second test, they are both **R8**.

The grayscale texture memory size is about 4x smaller than the color texture, so I expect to get **4x speed** in second test. however, I only get about **1.5x speed gain**.

Can anybody tell me if there is something wrong?

attach the code, first time both texture use .bgra8Unorm, second time use .r8Unorm,

```
kernel void
copyKernel(texture2d<half, access::read>  inTexture  [[texture(0)]],
           texture2d<half, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
           uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    half4 inColor  = inTexture.read(gid);
    outTexture.write(inColor, gid);
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that a smaller memory footprint will directly correlate to an equivalent speed increase.  Memory may not have been your bottleneck.  Please post code so that we can better understand your pipeline.  There is not much that we can go on based on your question right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: the following assumes that you are profiling your performance correctly (using [timer queries](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Timer_queries) and the like).

Every process has costs associated with it. There's the cost of actually doing the work, which includes memory accesses and the like. But there is also the cost of doing *anything*: the overhead of performing the process at all.

While the cost of doing the work tends to depend on how much work there is to do, the overhead costs are usually fixed. Which means that the less work you do, the *more* the overhead costs *relative* to that work.

So when you make your work less stressful, the performance of your process becomes more dependent on the fixed overhead of invoking the operation. In your case, the original 3-component texture copy was probably not a whole lot of work to begin with. So reducing the work, while improving performance, did nothing about the overhead of invoking that work.

Comment: Yes, the system do some optimization on texture reading and writing, so the total throughput is more than the theory memory bandwidth, so when I optimize my code and only get small gain, because the system already do some optimization